# Why can't I see the contents in Java char array neither in eclipse console nor in the debugger?

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, char

I not able to print char array to eclipse console or see the array contents while debugging in eclipse. I have written a program to return 1st non-repeating character index from a string using arrays. The program works & is very straightforward, but I find it very amusing that I cannot see the contents of the char array while I manipulate/debug the program. The SOP statement prints `null` OR `\u0000`. How can I see the actual contents of array 'a' in the below program ?

```
public static int getFirstNPCv2 (String s) {
    char a[] = new char[26];
    s=s.toLowerCase();
    for (char c : s.toCharArray()){
        a[c - 'a']++;
        //System.out.println(a[c - 'a']);
    }
    System.out.println(a);
    for (char c : s.toCharArray()){
        if(a[c - 'a'] == 1){
            return s.indexOf(c);
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

`getFirstNPCv2("titanic")` returns 3 which is correct, but why can't I see the contents of array 'a'

Comment: Hello @Vik, welcome to stackOverflow. Consider adding a tag for the programming language you are using.

Comment: Sure, just added. This is for Java.

Comment: Do you want to print the char array?

Comment: What are you hoping that a[c - 'a']++ will do?  for testing add System.out.println(c) to verify its what you expect.

Comment: @SPlatten `a[c - 'a']++` something happens with ASCII values there. He swaps or something like that. Not very intuitive.

Comment: He count the occurrences in a `String` that should only contains [a-zA-Z]. He remove `'a'` to get the corresponding index in the array `a`. `0 = a, 1 = b, ...`.

Answer (score 3):

This is because you don't hold any meaningful characters in your char array.
You are actually holding numbers in your char array. You created new char array and initial value of its elements is 0.

```
char a[] = new char[26];
```

Later on you will increment some elements of this array if they match index of character that is contained in your input string:

```
for (char c : s.toCharArray()){
    a[c - 'a']++;
    //System.out.println(a[c - 'a']);
}
```

Still, your char array doesn't hold any meaningful characters. It will have elements with values of 0,1,2,3... depending on your input string, and those values don't represent any readable letter or number. Still this doesn't prevent you from printing values stored in char array a. You can print them this way:

```
    for(int i = 0; i<a.length; i++)
    {
        int b = a[i];
        System.out.print(b);
    }
```

I think for your approach you should have used array of int. Happy coding.

Comment: Or even better to print `System.out.print(((char) i + 'a') + ":" + b);` to add the char representation. Filtering only those where `b >0` to only get interesting output.

Comment: But, why a[c - 'a']++ is even working as default values in char array are null OR \u0000 ?  a[c - 'a'] is like incrementing null. Any thoughts ??

Answer (score 0):

This is because you declared `a` as an array of characters and assign numeric values to each element.
In your case, all characters within the array have a value 0, 1 or 2.
These are non-printable characters.

Declare it as `int a[] = new int[26];`

Furthermore, instead of `System.out.println(a)`, you should use `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a))`.

Comment: But what if the OP wants to use a char array?